# Monitor communication of nodejs

Tags: node.js, monitor

Is there a node rifle that monitors communication between servers like a browser's network?

I want to check the request thrown to another server and the response returned from that server. Items to check are header of request and response, body of response.

Comment: You can use Morgan. app.use(morgan('tiny')); https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: @JudeDesir I want to monitor the network when sending xhr from the express server to another server, not the request for express server.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate time by performance-now

https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now

Just add two logs before and after your server request.